# how to make this mysql query fast? I have millions of data inside my table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called `ad_view` and it has 18.9 million number of data inside that table.

This is the table design of `ad_vew`

```
ad_view
-------
ad_id
network_id
publisher_id
landingpage_id
advertiser_id
```

I am using this query to get the `ad_id` and the count of `ad_id` depending on the `network_id`, so in this case the `network_id` is `4`.

```
select ad_id,count(ad_id) as strength 
from ad_view 
where network_id = 4 
group by ad_id 
order by strength desc 
limit 10
```

This query takes forever to load. Do you have any suggestion how to make this query fast?

I am not a database expert, if it takes to redesign this table, I would do that.

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: create index and get the data by using limit and offset try to use pagination

Comment: Is it not possible to to the counting of the data programmaticly instead of using SQL? Also, look at indexing.

Comment: To all: in the `order by` clause, can the column name `strength` come after `desc`?  I thought it had to be `order by strength desc`?

Comment: Try create index on network_id as your are searching the column and probably it is taking more time. Indexing this column will make your search faster and hence query also.

Comment: I want to learn about indexing too. @TS please include data type at the structure.

Comment: Can You separate/move unused record to another table, so you can reduce 18.9 million number of data? So You can load your data if needed, using union select. And Your ad_view (original table) more minified. Maybe something like "SELECT * INTO AD_VIEW_BACKUP FROM ad_view WHERE <Your filter>" (Select into query and add where to filter your unused data, try google for it.)

Answer (score 3):

This will help:

```
ALTER TABLE ad_view ADD INDEX (network_id, ad_id).
```

Make sure you have tuned your `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to hold the frequently-requested portion of your table in memory.

You might like my presentation, [How to Design Indexes, Really](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-design-indexes-really). That presentation doesn't go into indexing for `GROUP BY`, but you can think of it like a range condition.

Answer (score 3):

**1** Create an index on `network_id` since you're searching by it

```
ALTER TABLE `ad_view`  ADD INDEX (`network_id`);
```

**2** If you're trying to get the count of `ad_id` for a given `network_id`, why do you need `ad_id` in your results?  and why do you need to `order by`?  I don't understand this. If all you want is *how many ad_ids for network_id 4*, then do:

```
SELECT COUNT(IF(network_id=4,1,null)) as strength from ad_view
```

It will return just a number.  See [**this demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f72885/2)

PS: your initial post included a broken query (in the `order by` clause), which you changed after I made a comment.  Your current query still doesn't give you what you say you want.  I just tried it [on this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8a249c/1)